# CodeIgniter cache files removing public access

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I am using Phil Sturgeon's cache library.

I have my cache files stored in "root/app/cache" folder.

"app" folder has ".htaccess" with "Deny from all", so when you try to go there in browser, you get "forbidden" message.

"cache" folder doesn't have ".htaccess" but when I try to go there I still get "forbidden" message. This is all good.

But when I try to go to a specific cache file in that folder, I can actually see the content of the file. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add into the .htaccess a RewriteCondition and redirect to an empty place, causing a 404 error. Anything may work, just take this example and change it to your convenience...

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule   ^/apps/(.*)  ^/someplaceelse/$1 [L,R]
```

Thansk!

@leo.